# Error during Install Xtensa-lx106 GNU toolchain

Tags: esp8266, kaa

I'm trying to install SDK for ESP8266 for working with kaa.
I'm use this guide
https://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/ESP8266
but during stage

```
./ct-ng xtensa-lx106-elf
./ct-ng build
```

I got error

```
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20180406.213426
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_mpc_get[scripts/build/companion_libs/140-mpc.sh@741]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_libs_get[scripts/build/companion_libs.sh@15]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@583]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      'share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.20.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:07.12)
[00:08] / make: *** [build] Помилка 1
```

What should I do? How can I live on?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function do_mpc_get() is trying to download the MPC tarball from a unavailable resource. You can try to edit this function on the script

> scripts/build/companion_libs/140-mpc.sh

and use the following lines instead:

```
do_mpc_get() {
CT_GetFile "mpc-${CT_MPC_VERSION}" .tar.gz      \
    https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc
}
```

If the error persist and the required tarballs still missing, you can manually download it and put them on the tarball directory, and proceed the build.

> /crosstool-NG/.build/tarballs